# How to copy files to be deleted with rsync ?

Tags: file, copy, backup, rsync

the output of 
rsync -avzn --delete lists the files to be deleted . I mount the files system with samba and then i can get a list of the files to be deleted with 
| grep deleting

eg (its windows so there a space in the filenames)

```
deleting janes/pass the parcel.jpg
deleting janes/Noname.jpg
deleting janes/111EUVAT.jpg
```

I'd like to copy them somewhere 'just in case'  SWMBO realises that she has made a mistake. I can list  just the files to be deleted with
 | grep deleting

what do I do next to copy them somewhere . Something with xargs ????

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

options -b and --backup-dir=/path/to/dir and rsync puts the files in the backup-dir. And you can then do whatever you want with them !